# send email in android app, choose email address to use

Tags: android, email

We have contracted out an Android app, and our clients are not happy.  Can we do what we want?

THe scenario is an activity that lists data about an event, and a button to compose the email.  That works.  Except that it always uses the google account on the phone.  Can email be sent in accounts other than the google account outside of the Mail app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When your program hands off the information to another application via an `Intent`, any program capable of receiving that type of `Intent` can take it. In this instance, any properly-designed e-mail client should be available to handle the job unless the program is specifically calling to the GMail client instead.